# Wix - Run custom action based on windows version condition

Tags: wix, window, installation

I'm trying to create a custom action that runs on specific windows versions. It works ?

```
Custom Action="DoSomething" After="CostInitialize"> 
<![CDATA[VersionNT >= 600]]> 
</Custom>
```

What is the best way to do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried your sample? What does not work there? BTW, you might want to take a look at the [Common MSI Conditions Cheat Sheet](http://resources.flexerasoftware.com/web/pdf/archive/IS-CHS-Common-MSI-Conditions.pdf)

Comment: I used <![CDATA[VersionNT >= 600]]> without success. I'll try to put in my CustomAction the expression (VersionNT != 501) to only allow installation if the SO version is different of Windows XP, without "CDATA" as is defined in  the doc that u send. Thank u @YanSklyarenko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. To prevent installation based on operational system condition i used:

```
<CustomAction Id="DoSomething" BinaryKey="CustomAction.CA.dll" DllEntry="DoSomething" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

 <InstallExecuteSequence>
    Custom Action="DoSomething" After="CostInitialize"> 
    <![CDATA[NOT(VersionNT = 501)]]>
    </Custom>
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When "501" is relative to OS Version (501 = Windows XP).

ThankU.